# Imprecise height and getItemLayout in react native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using [`getItemLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout) to improve the performance of my `SectionList` in React Native. I'm supposed to return the height of items, which is working, but I've noticed that the actual height of components can vary on Android:

[image]

This causes noticeable shifting when I scroll far down the list--seemingly because when it actually renders the list items the height differs from what I've returned from `getItemLayout` sometimes up to 1 dp.

Is there a more accurate way to implement `getItemLayout` so that there is no shifting after scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the same issue.
Try setting height using

`PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel().`